# Optimize function to order a two-dimensional array by the value of its position 0 in C

Tags: performance, sorting, c89

```c
double generation[genomes_per_generation][amount_of_variables];
double ranked_generation[genomes_per_generation][1 + amount_of_variables];
double tmp[1 + amount_of_variables];
int i, j, k;
for (i = 0; i < gens_per_generation; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < gens_per_generation; j++) {
        if (ranked_generation[j][0] > ranked_generation[i][0]) {
            for (k = 0; k < 1 + amount_of_variables; k++) {
                tmp[k] = ranked_generation[i][k];
                ranked_generation[i][k] = ranked_generation[j][k];
                ranked_generation[j][k] = tmp[k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My intention is to move the rows of the array depending on the initial value as shown in my current code, the problem with this is that although it works, it is slow. I tried to use `qsort()` but it only gave me segmentation faults.

If anyone comes up with any tricks with pointers, memory align or whatever, please let me know.

Comment: You can either implement a faster, O(n log n) algorithm, or you can fix the issue you have with `qsort`. Which way do you want to go?

Comment: @Aziz This is for a complex Genetic Algorithm, what do your recommend Sr? Im searching for the best performance.

Comment: If you have the code where you attempted using `qsort`, please post it and we can figure out the issue with it. I highly suggest using it instead of writing your own sort algorithm.

Comment: Note that variable-length arrays are not valid in C89 AFAIR. Thus, variables like `genomes_per_generation` or `ammount_of_variables` needs to be compile-time constants. Besides this, the arrays needs to be small to fit in the stack (typically ~1 MiB but the actual size it platform-dependent). Otherwise, there will be typically a stack overflow or a segmentation fault (undefined behaviour). To solve this, you need to use *dynamic allocation*.

Comment: @JérômeRichard genomes_per_generation = 1000 and ammount_of_variables = 4 both are #define.

Comment: Ok so this is totally fine :) .

Comment: @JérômeRichard Any idea how to improve this? i cant get to work qsort()

Answer (score 2):

Your current algorithm looks like a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) which runs in `O(n²)` time (where `n` is the `genomes_per_generation` here). Your overall algorithm runs in `O(m n²)` (where `m` is `amount_of_variables`). Using `qsort` is indeed a goo strategy since it should use a `n log n` sorting algorithm (typically an [introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort)).

This following code should work (untested):

```c
int compareFun(const void* block_a, const void* block_b)
{
    double first_a = *(const double*)block_a;
    double first_b = *(const double*)block_b;

    // Optimizing compilers like Clang generate a fast branch-less code here
    if(first_a < first_b)
        return -1;
    if(first_a > first_b)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

// In your computing function:
size_t itemSize = (1 + amount_of_variables) * sizeof(double); // In bytes!
qsort(ranked_generation, genomes_per_generation, itemSize, compareFun);
```

The idea is that `qsort` works on blocks of `n` bytes and you should not forget to multiply the size of a block by `sizeof(double)`. The comparison function only compare the first item of each block like in the initial code. Note that the above code assumes `ranked_generation` is filled with correct values (the original code does not fill it and does not use `generation` either).

Comment: Implement it and compile!! but it has only one flaw, it is only moving position 0 of ranked_generation, my code moves the entire row since position 0 is a reference to the next 4 variables

Comment: I just tested and it works fine on my machine. Here is the testing code: https://pastebin.com/hdcmMXDc . Here is the result: https://pastebin.com/vT2PZ00d .